# Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'. throw FallThroughError();

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I don't know where to put the FallThroughError(); method.

Comment: Can you tell me your firebase dependency versions and also dart and flutter versions? Also while you're at it can you search your whole project for `FallThroughError` method using CTRL + Shift + F on Windows and Linux or CMD + Shift + F on Mac in Android Studio

Comment: firebase_core: ^1.15.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.15
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13

Answer (score 23):

Run the Flutter command to update the dependencies.

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

This should fix the issue by updating the `cloud_firestore_platform_interface` as follows.

[image: cloud_firestore_platform_interface version update]

#### iOS

On iOS you might get this error when running the project.

[image: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.]

To fix this issue,

- Delete the `Podfile.lock` under the iOS folder
- Navigate to iOS folder, by running `cd ios` in the terminal.
- Run the command `pod install --repo-update`

The app should now run fine.

Answer (score 4):

upgrade your dependencies to latest version it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the solution that’s working for me :

1. run this command first **flutter pub upgrade --major-versions**
2. then run this one **flutter pub outdated**

Answer (score 1):

I tried a flutter clean. Then recompiled but it still threw the error. I have run **flutter pub upgrade --major-versions**, then **flutter pub outdated** to make sure there is no large version gap.

I am 100% sure that this will resolve your error because i just tried that.

May be tis will solve your FALLTHROUGHERROR() and will give some random error for file i wil update that to

Answer (score 1):

yup! as told above, upgrading your dependencies is a crucial thing...

running `flutter pub upgrade` doesn't help much -- it just upgrades to a particular level. but it doesn't get all your dependencies to latest version on pub.dev

> so only thing to do is upgrade them MANUALLY, the same way you pasted the package with version in yaml file, while installing...

I had to do this when I was getting back to my 1.5year old project

Comment: what's up with the blockquote?  who are you quoting there?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error "Failed to build build_runner:build_runner" in Flutter, you can follow these steps:

Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
```

After running these commands, try running the build_runner command again:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

These commands will clean your project, upgrade the dependencies to the latest versions, fetch the dependencies, and then attempt to build the project again using build_runner.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the "Failed to build build_runner:build_runner" error.

Answer (score 0):

run
flutter pub upgrade
it worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Just run this in your terminal:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter packages get`
3. `flutter downgrade`
4. `flutter run`

Thats worked for me!