# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Flutter Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

I am trying to run a flutter application. But I am running into this error : * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

But still couldn't get this right. Below is the error message that I am getting :

```
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
 - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/arjunmalhotra/Desktop/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/arjunmalhotra/Desktop/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried solutions on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861470/error-method-not-found-fallthrougherror-throw-fallthrougherror)